# `std::vector` 'substring concatenator'

Tags: c++, strings, vectors

The point of this is to concatenate a vector of `std::string`s into one string starting at an index of the vector.

```
std::string vectorSubstr(std::vector<std::string> vec, int startPos, char seperator)
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    for (int i = startPos; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i == startPos)
        {
            ss << vec[i];
        }
        else
        {
            ss << seperator << vec[i];
        }
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Should  I be using a stringstream or just concatenating strings?

Comment: what does startPos signify?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal the index at which the function starts concatenating the vector. The reason for this is say I have a vector with some nonsense data at the beginning but the last few indexes have a message. I'd use this function in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `std::[o]stringstream` vs `std::string::append()`/`std::string::operator+=()`

With `std::string::append()`, you'll usually pay the initial allocation, and with each append you'll pay for a data copy and possibly an allocation.  Constructing `std::ostringstream` is more complex compared to string.  You have to initialize the stream, the states, and the locale.  Every `std::ostringstream::operator<<()` call accrues a possible allocation, a data copy, and state checks.  Once you've completed that, you have to invoke `std::stringstream::str()` to use the string, which involves a copy (depending on implementation).

With C++11 introducing non-member `std::to_string()` and `std::stoXX()` conversion functions and all the various format libraries out there, I haven't really found a use for `std::ostringstream` recently.

### Explicit Typing

`std::stringstream` inherits from both `std::istringstream` and `std::ostringstream`.  You'll find that rarely will you have to both read and write from a stream, so be explicit in your intent and use the `std::[i|o]stringstream` type.

### Interface

`vectorSubstr()` could be confusing for some people.  Does it return a `std::vector<std::string>` of substrings?  Consider other names like `to_string()`, `join()`, `concatenate()`.

Prefer writing range-based algorithms using the [Iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) that is heavily used by the STL.

If you do not plan on changing the contents of a parameter, `const`-qualify it.

Your parameter for the container is taken By-Value.  Copies on containers (and non-primitives) can be expensive, so pass those arguments By-Reference (`&`).

```
std::string join(const std::vector<std::string> &input, const char separator)
```

### Algorithm

You can reduce the amount of branching you have to do by handling the first element case, then your delimiter becomes naturally infixed.

### Putting It Together

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename Separator>
inline typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
join(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Separator& separator) {
  using ResultType = std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type;
  ResultType result;

  if (first != last) {
    result += *first;
    ++first;
  }

  for (; first != last; ++first) {
    result += separator;
    result += *first;
  }

  return result;
}

int main() {
  const std::vector<std::string> inputs = {"a", "bcd", "efghijklm", "nopqrstuvwxyz"};
  const auto first = std::next(std::begin(inputs), 2);
  const auto last = std::end(inputs);

  std::cout << join(first, last, ", ") << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to concatenate `vector<string>` elements, why not use the following approach:

```
std::string seperator = " ";
std::string vectorElementHolder;

for (const auto& word : vec){

    vectorElementHolder += word + seperator;

}
```

Simple and effective, assuming you use C++11.
If you want to change the index where you start, you could always declare an iterator as such `vector<string>::iterator` to point to the index and go from there.

Comment: `word` should either be taken by const reference or it should be moved into `+=` if a copy is made. Also this leaves a trailing separator.

Comment: Since `word` is not being changed, I agree it should be const reference. As to fix the trailing separator, `vectorElementHolder.pop_back()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything wrong with this approach? Should I be using a stringstream or just concatenating strings?

I use a different approach: I have created a class similar to std::ostream_iterator (see the utility functions at the end of the code for example use):

```
#pragma once

#include <iosfwd>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

namespace stdex {

    /**
     *  @brief  Implements join functionality directing the output into an ostream
     *
     *  This class provides an iterator for writing into an ostream. The type T is
     *  the only type written by this iterator and there must be an
     *  operator << (T) defined.
     * 
     *  @code
     * 
     * template<typename T> using join = ostream_join_iterator<T>;
     * std::ostringstream out;
     * std::vector<std::string> strings{"alpha", "beta", "gamma"};
     * std::copy(strings.begin(), strings.end(), join<string>{out, ", "});
     * assert(out.str() == "alpha, beta, gamma");
     * 
     *  @endcode
     * 
     *  @remarks This class implements functionality similar to
     *      std::ostream_iterator except it does not print a separator after the
     *      last element.
     *
     *  @param  T  The type to write to the ostream.
     *  @param  C  The ostream char_type.
     *  @param  Tr The ostream char_traits.
     */
    template<typename T, typename C=char, typename Tr=std::char_traits<C> >
    class ostream_join_iterator
    : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
    {
    public:
        typedef C  char_type;
        typedef Tr traits_type;
        typedef std::basic_string<C, Tr>  splitter_type;
        typedef std::basic_ostream<C, Tr> ostream_type;

    private:
        ostream_type        *out_;
        splitter_type       splitter_;
        bool                at_first_;

    public:
        ostream_join_iterator(ostream_type& out)
        : out_{&out}
        , splitter_{}
        , at_first_{true}
        {
        }

        /**
         *  Construct from an ostream.
         *
         *  @remarks The delimiter is not copied, and thus must not be destroyed
         *          while this iterator is in use.
         *
         *  @param  out         Underlying ostream to write to.
         *  @param  splitter    CharT delimiter string to insert.
         */
        ostream_join_iterator(ostream_type& out, const char_type* splitter)
        : out_{&out}
        , splitter_{splitter}
        , at_first_{true}
        {
        }

        /// Copy constructor.

        ostream_join_iterator(const ostream_join_iterator& other)
        : out_{other.out_}
        , splitter_{other.splitter_}
        , at_first_{other.at_first_}
        {
        }

        ostream_join_iterator& operator=(const T& value)
        {
            if((not splitter_.empty()) and (not at_first_))
                *out_ << splitter_;
            *out_ << value;
            at_first_ = false;
            return *this;
        }

        ostream_join_iterator& operator=(ostream_join_iterator temp)
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(out_, temp.out_);
            swap(splitter_, temp.splitter_);
            swap(at_first_, temp.at_first_);
            return *this;
        }

        ostream_join_iterator&
        operator*() {
            return *this;
        }

        ostream_join_iterator&
        operator++() {
            return *this;
        }

        ostream_join_iterator&
        operator++(int) {
            return *this;
        }
    };

    // join implementation with string separator

    template<typename It, typename C, typename Tr, typename A>
    void join(const It& begin, const It& end,
    const std::basic_string<C,Tr,A>& separator, std::basic_ostream<C,Tr>& out)
    {
        std::copy(begin, end,
            ostream_join_iterator<std::remove_reference<decltype(*begin)>>{out, separator});
    }

    template<typename It, typename C, typename Tr, typename A>
    std::basic_string<C,Tr,A> join(const It& begin, const It& end,
    const std::basic_string<C,Tr,A>& separator)
    {
        std::basic_ostringstream<C,Tr,A>  buffer{};
        join(begin, end, separator, buffer);
        return buffer.str();
    }

    template<typename S, typename C, typename Tr, typename A>
    void join(const S& sequence,
    const std::basic_string<C,Tr,A>& separator,
    std::basic_ostream<C,Tr>& out)
    {
        join(std::begin(sequence), std::end(sequence), separator, out);
    }

    template<typename S, typename C, typename Tr, typename A>
    std::basic_string<C,Tr,A> join(
    const S& sequence,
    const std::basic_string<C,Tr,A>& separator)
    {
        std::basic_ostringstream<C,Tr,A>  buffer{};
        join(std::begin(sequence), std::end(sequence), separator, buffer);
        return buffer.str();
    }

    // join implementation with character literal separator

    template<typename It>
    void join(const It& begin, const It& end,
    const char separator[], std::ostream& out)
    {
        typedef decltype(*begin) iterated;
        std::copy(begin, end, ostream_join_iterator<iterated>{out, separator});
    }

    template<typename It>
    std::string join(const It& begin, const It& end, const char separator[])
    {
        std::ostringstream  buffer{};
        join(begin, end, separator, buffer);
        return buffer.str();
    }
} // stdex
```